# Make Axios to pass and send cookies in its requests automatically

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex, laravel-sanctum

I want to pass authorization token automatically so I don't have to do it every time I send a request.

I am using Laravel and Sanctum to handle API and tried to follow everything that is suggested in documentation so I share it with you , so you can help me.

I added these lines to app/Http/Kernel.php

```php
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

In my config/cors.php file :

```php
.
.
.
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Ok these were my server side configuration and here is my Vue.js :

my app.js

```javascript
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './routes';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from './store/index.js'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

import App from './components/App.vue';

store.dispatch('getUser').then(() => {
    const app = createApp(App);
    app.use(router);
    app.use(store);
    app.mount('#app');
});
```

here is store/index.js file that handles vuex :

```javascript
import {createStore} from 'vuex';

const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            authenticated: false,
            user: null
        }
    },
    getters: {
        authenticated(state) {
            return state.authenticated
        },
        user(state) {
            return state.user
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthenticated(state, payload) {
            state.authenticated = payload;
        },
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async signIn({commit}, payload) {
            try{
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

                const res = await axios.post('/api/authenticate',payload);

                if(res.data.status_code == 200) {
                    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
                        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + res.data.access_token;
                        return config;
                    }, function (error) {
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    });
                    return store.dispatch('getUser');
                } else {
                    throw res.message;
                }
            } catch(e) {
                throw 'User can not be authenticated'
            }
        },

        async getUser({commit}) {
            await axios.get('/api/user').then(res => {
                commit('setUser', res.data);
                commit('setAuthenticated', true);
            }).catch(() => {
                commit('setUser', null);
                commit('setAuthenticated', false);
            })
        },

        async logout({commit}) {
            await axios.post('/api/logout').then(res => {
                commit('setUser', null);
                commit('setAuthenticated', false);
            }).catch(() => {
                commit('setUser', null);
                commit('setAuthenticated', false);
            })
        }
    }
});

export default store;
```

As you see I have to intercept axios with authorization token. But when I reload the page I get the problem and have to login again.

Comment: I see you're using `http://` and not `https://` - browsers treat secure-contexts differently, so that might have something to do with it (while there is intent for browsers to treat `http://localhost` and `https://localhost` identically, they currently don't: https://chromestatus.com/feature/6269417340010496 )